# What is the best way to inject database connection in a MEAN stack app?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I have seen [examples](https://github.com/cwbuecheler/node-tutorial-2-restful-app) that put database connection in request object and retrieve it when needed.

What is the best way to inject database connection in a MEAN stack app?

Comment: I use mongoose and I require my model's file at the very start of www Express file. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use mongoose and put the connection details into it.
When you initialize that or start the node server it will automatically initialize the connection and create collections and document schema into that.